# Create a Single Border Around All UIButtons Xamarin

Tags: mono, xamarin

I have roughly 10 buttons in my iOS application using Xamarin and I am looking for a simple way to put a single, black border around all my buttons. Is there a way to do this without hard coding the border into all the buttons?

So far to put a single border around one button I have:

```
numOne.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
numOne.Layer.CornerRadius = 4;
numOne.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
```

Is there a way to go about doing this for all the buttons that I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you could create a method that returns the preferred button:

```
public static class DefaultUIElements
{
    public static UIButton GenericButton
    {
        get
        {
            UIButton button = new UIButton(UIButtonType.Custom);
            button.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
            button.Layer.CornerRadius = 4;
            button.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
            return button;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your own Button class

(This code is just of the top of my head, and not tested in an IDE)

```
public class MyButton : UIButton
{
    MyButton()
    {
        Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
        Layer.CornerRadius = 4;
        Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
    }
}
```